# TinyPic.com wants me to use Photobucket to login?

Tags: login, photobucket, tinypic

I'm trying to register an account with TinyPic.com and it tells me to register with Photobucket.  I've been registered at Photobucket.com for something like ten years. When I type my username and password from Photobucket.com into TinyPic.com it doesn't let me in.

Since there's no registration page, how do I go about registering for TinyPic.com exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyPic were [bought out by Photobucket](http://blog.photobucket.com/blog/2010/09/welcome-tinypic-users.html).

Looks like Photobucket are trying to improve their service to do all the things that TinyPic.com did, therefore negating the need to login to TinyPic any more.